# Correctly inserting parameter

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form that requires validation, decided to do it a little differently than usual and have the main function call smaller functions like so

```
function validate() {
 validate_this(*fieldId*);
 validate_that(*fieldId*);
 ...
}
```

where the smaller functions are like so:

```
function validate_empty(formField) {
 if ( formName.formField.value.length = 0; ) {
  //Do Stuff
 }
}
```

where `formField` is the fields ID within the form.
This however is causing an error on the `formName.formField.value.length`

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

How can I get this to be parsing the actual fieldId through instead of a string or null? jQuery is out of the question.

Comment: `formName[formField]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) instead:

```
function validate_empty(formField) {
    if ( document.getElementById(formField).value.length == 0 ) {
        //Do Stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Knew it would be a simple fix but didn't think it'd be that simple. Thanks a heap!

Comment: the semi-colon is a syntax error here, as is the assignment operator: assigning to a read-only property is a bit of a no-no

Comment: Nice catch, both of those were simple typo's creating this question, not in the actual code though so all is well

Answer (score 1):

The way your code look, JS is scope-scanning for a variable called `formName`, or whatever the form's name actually is... you should specify that it's a DOM element: `document.forms[0]` or similar.

Even so, your `if` will always evaluate to true, because you're assigning, not comparing:

```
var foo = 0;//single  = : assignment operator
console.log(foo == '0');//true, loose comparison (type coerced)
console.log(foo === '0');//false, strict comp: type && value
```

Quite apart from that, the way you're validating your form is *highly* questionable... You seem to be using JS as if it were a language like C or something. JS IMHO, is best used as an event-driven, functional programming language. 
So even though this isn't strictly relevant ATM, please do consider looking into the strengths of JS... It's a neat little language, that doesn't deserve this kind of abuse.

Comment: So Using `formName.field.etc` where the forms name is `formName` is a no no? (even though it works)

Comment: @aprice: Nope: for one, you can inadvertatly hide mask the formName (variable), and I wouldn't at all be surprized if there were some X-browser issues

Comment: I see, good to know.
Personally wouldn't have set it up like this but it's for a university assignment where it says the validation is to have no repeated code.   Must admit my C# instincts jumped in and this is the result